# why the version of library in my project is different from it's parent pom declaration?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I simplify my project structure and find some clues. My project structure looks like the following:

```
-------- project 1 ---------
parent
     |_ project-a
        |_ src
        |_ pom.xml
     |_ pom.xml

------- project 2 ----------
project-b
     |_ src
     |_ pom.xml

---------------------------
```

In project 1, parent is maven parent for project-a, it's pom.xml looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- spring boot parent -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>A custom project using myfaces</name>
    <url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

    <modules>
        <module>project-a</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

In parent's pom, it declares spring boot as it's maven parent and project-a as it's module. In project-a, it's pom is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>project-a Maven Webapp</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <testSource>1.8</testSource>
                    <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

project-b is a standalone project, it's pom looks like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- parent declaration is the key point of this problem! -->
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-b</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>A custom project using myfaces</name>
    <url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

    <!-- Project dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

After installing project 1 by *mvn install*, the dependency tree of project-b is as follows:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ project-b ---
[INFO] com.demo:project-b:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.demo:project-a:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.16:runtime
```

But if I remove the parent declaration in project-b's pom, the dependency tree of project-b is what I expected:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ project-b ---
[INFO] com.demo:project-b:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.demo:project-a:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.11:runtime
```

I also have tried to remove the parent dependency of spring boot in project 1 parent's pom, after reinstalling project 1, and the result is what I expected too. so I guess the parent declaration is the key point, but why?

Best Regards.

Comment: this is what is pulling in the sql connector `com.love4bb:db:jar:0.0.2` but you havn't disclosed what this is.

Comment: First of all, if project A is a _Parent POM_, it needs to have `<packaging>pom</packaging>`.

Comment: the version 8.0.16 is a dependency of com.love4bb:db, you have need to add a exclusion to use the declared version in project-a

Comment: @ThomasAndolf It's my fault, I renamed the Project-A package name from com.love4bb, I have updated the dependency tree of Project-B.

Comment: @JFMeier I have edited my question and described my problem more clearer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because parent's dependency has more higher priority than project-a's one.
You can refer to this document.
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

> Dependency mediation - this determines what version of an artifact will be chosen when multiple versions are encountered as dependencies. Maven picks the "nearest definition". That is, it uses the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM. Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, the first declaration wins.
>
> "nearest definition" means that the version used will be the closest one to your project in the tree of dependencies. For example, if dependencies for A, B, and C are defined as A -> B -> C -> D 2.0 and A -> E -> D 1.0, then D 1.0 will be used when building A because the path from A to D through E is shorter. You could explicitly add a dependency to D 2.0 in A to force the use of D 2.0.

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
```

Since this module also has a dependency of mysql-connector-java(8.0.16), maven use this instead of project-a's one.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.6.RELEASE

```
project-b
parent
|----mysql-connector-java(8.0.16)   <- maven choose this because its level is higher
|----project-a
     |----mysql-connector-java(8.0.11)
```

Maybe like this..? (please let me know if I'm miss understood)

Comment: I think you are right, parent declaration will make project-b extend it's parent dependencies. So in the dependency tree the mysql-connector-java(8.0.16) path is shorter than the mysql-connector-java(8.0.11) path. I was mislead by the dependency tree display of project-b, because it shows the mysql-connector-java(8.0.16) comes from project-a instead of project-b's parent. thank you!